# BehaviorSubject in asynchronous callback not updating in HTML view ionic

Tags: html, angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am trying to make a variable update its value in front-end in an Ionic App. The variable updates in the front end if I touch any ion-button but not when its value updates.

In the .html file I have got:

```
<p>{{ scantext$ | async }}</p>
```

In the .ts file I have got:

```
export class HomePage {
....
this.bluetoothle.startScan(scanparams).subscribe(this.startScanSub);
....
startScanSub = {
    next: device => this.addToText('subscribe:' + JSON.stringify(device)),
    error: err => this.addToText('subscribe: ' + JSON.stringify(err)),
    complete: () => this.addToText('subscribe Complete'),
};
scantext$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('init');

addToText(device){
    this.scantext$.next(device);
    console.log(device);
}
....
```

I am sure the variable is changing its value because I can see the Logs as information comes in from the subscription. However, in the front-end I cannot see how the variable changes its value, unless I touch a button in the application.

How can I make the variable change in the front-end automatically ?

Comment: Can you write your current result? What appears in console and what you can see on screen before click? There is still 'init' text?

Comment: Before I click, I can see "init". When I click, the subscription ocurrs and after 1 or 2 seconds, "init" changes to "{"status": "scanStarted"}", this seems to be working Ok. However, during the scan, console.log(device); is fired multiple times, but the text keeps unchanged ("{"status": "scanStarted"}"). I wrapped this.scantext$.next(device); with console.log("Before"); and console.log("After"); and I can see both logs, so this.scantext$.next(device); has to be triggering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am sure the variable is changing its value because I can see the
>   Logs as information comes in from the subscription. However, in the
>   front-end I cannot see how the variable changes its value, unless I
>   touch a button in the application.

Looks like data is not being tracked.

There are some solutions, use `NgZone` or `ChangeDetectorRef`

**NgZone**

```js
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {
    ...
  }
}
```

```js
addToText(device) {
   this._zone.run(() => this.scantext$.next(device));
   console.log(device); 
}
```

**ChangeDetectorRef**

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class HomePage {
  constructor (private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    ...
  }
}
```

```js
addToText(device){
   this.scantext$.next(device);
   console.log(device);
   this._cdr.detectChanges();
}
```